# can not use the value immediately set by useState

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm stuck in a problem related to react `useState` and not sure how to solve it.

Some background. I've a register form with validation on blur on each field. The validation works if I blur individual field which is basically setting the error message (using `useState`) if there's any error. I've called the same validation methods on form submit. So that I don't have to write a duplicate code.

The problem arise when I submit without invoking the blur methods. It runs all the methods and set the error messages but the `useState` values are not available. I read some articles that says to use `useEffect` but then it will either run without any watcher or with watchers. If it runs without any watcher then the ux will be bad and user will be shown errors when they freshly come to the page. [Please see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OInMt.png)

OR

If we add watchers in our `useEffect` then validation will be run on each key stroke which I don't want.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    handleOnBlur("firstname", firstname);
    handleOnBlur("lastname", lastname);
    handleOnBlurPassword(password);
},[firstname, lastname, password])
```

I'm looking to solve this without `useEffect` or some other way in which I don't compromise the UX.

I've created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-fog-yr07fi?file=/src/App.js). Please have a look if my i'm not clear in my description

Comment: How can a user submit with invoking an `blur` event from the field?

Comment: You can't use the new state before a re-render. You must pass the new value as an argument to any function that wants it.

Comment: @vsync please have a look at the attached codesandbox

Comment: @HasanAga I'm already passing the value if you checkout the codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another validations step on the `onSubmit` event, or, if the form is submitted without this React event, then manually **run validations** just *before submitting the data to the server*, and obviously, if the form is deemed "invalid", do not continue (do not save the form on the server)

Put your **complete** form validation step here, instead of those 3 marked lines:

[image]

Create a function that validates all the fields and returns `true` if everything is valid, and only then proceed with the actual form submission.

Comment: How do I invoke an event before submitting form? Do you have any example

Comment: I think creating another function for validation will be duplication of code

Comment: it is not duplication. You should almost always validate the form before it's submitted, and my answer is the correct one, from ~20 years experience of writing HTML forms with javascript and also a [package for form validations](https://github.com/yairEO/validator)

reconstruct your code in a manner that makes sense, so fields will get validated on `blur` event, individually, and all together on `submit` event (at the location shown in the screenshot of my answer)

Comment: I think yeah you are right. I have put all the logic in util including messages and now I just import those util methods in the component. Something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-euclid-qm3eqo?file=/src/App.js), right?

Comment: Yes kind of like this.
This code is far far from good code, but it is better than before. You don't need to hold a state for each field individually. You can create one state for the values of the whole form, as an Object, with keys that represent each field.

Comment: I have refactored the code based on your comment. How does it look now? or you have more suggestions?

Comment: Well, there is a lot of refactoring and re-writing I would do, but that is for another question :) For this one I have provided you with a satisfactory solution. You can selected this as answer and settle it, and if you wish, open a new question asking about refactoring advises

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with React but I think for this kind of forms it's best practice to use React useRef hook instead of useState.
This way the state will not change with every type of the user.
You can use the useEffect with empty brackets for the mount (first render) and add another useEffect with names and password dependecies for later checks.
Hope this is helpful :)

Comment: I didn't get how can i use `useRef` in place of `useState`. How are the validation going to work?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may use useRef() instead of useState using following syntax :
const firstName = useRef() and obtain firstname's values as firstname.current.value.
Following link might help you : w3schools.com/react/react_useref.asp

Comment: You mean for the error object or input field value?

Comment: You may use it whenever you want to save or refer values. Right now, you should try it with input feild value.

Comment: yeah I can but the problem is related to error object. How using `useRef` in input fields is going to solve my problem for error object not being updated with `useState`

Comment: following video may help you dealing with your validations ,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GfWJLK6S1Ec&t=570s

Comment: What I get is , you might having problem dealing with form validations, So from my side I learnt form validations from the following video , hope it really really helps : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brcHK3P6ChQ&list=PL0Zuz27SZ-6PRCpm9clX0WiBEMB70FWwd  , have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

According to the defined requirement i have updated the code.
Please look into it and update the changes as well.

> previous code and need to change : The errors have been set if there is no value, but haven't set if there is a value.

This code might be helpful to you.

thank you so much !

**App.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [firstname, setFirstname] = useState("");
  const [lastname, setLastname] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessages, setErrorMessages] = useState({
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    password: ""
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    handleOnBlur("firstname", firstname);
    handleOnBlur("lastname", lastname);
    handleOnBlurPassword(password);
  }, []);
  const handleOnSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
    handleOnBlur("firstname", firstname);
    handleOnBlur("lastname", lastname);
    handleOnBlurPassword(password);

    const hasError = Object.values(errorMessages).find(
      (value) => value.length > 0
    );
    if (!hasError) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        // mocking api
        console.log("Api response here::");
        setLoading(false);
      }, 5000);
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  const handleOnBlur = (label, value) => {
    if (!value) {
      setErrorMessages((errMsgs) => ({
        ...errMsgs,
        [label]: `Please enter your ${label}`
      }));
    } else {
      setErrorMessages((errMsgs) => ({
        ...errMsgs,
        [label]: ""
      }));
    }
  };
  const handleOnBlurPassword = (value) => {
    if (!value) {
      setErrorMessages((errMsgs) => ({
        ...errMsgs,
        password: `Please enter your password`
      }));
    } else {
      setErrorMessages((errMsgs) => ({
        ...errMsgs,
        password: ""
      }));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start Registering!!</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
        <div className="text-input">
          <label htmlFor="firstname" className="">
            First name:
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="firstname"
            value={firstname}
            onChange={(e) => setFirstname(e.target.value)}
            onBlur={(e) => handleOnBlur("firstname", e.target.value)}
            placeholder="First name"
          />
          {errorMessages.firstname && <p>{errorMessages.firstname}</p>}
        </div>
        <div className="text-input">
          <label htmlFor="firstname">Last name: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="lastname"
            value={lastname}
            onChange={(e) => setLastname(e.target.value)}
            onBlur={(e) => handleOnBlur("lastname", e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Last name"
          />
          {errorMessages.lastname && <p>{errorMessages.lastname}</p>}
        </div>
        <div className="text-input">
          <label htmlFor="firstname">Password: </label>
          <input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            onBlur={(e) => handleOnBlurPassword(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Password"
          />
          {errorMessages.password && <p>{errorMessages.password}</p>}
        </div>
        <button disabled={loading} type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: this will show error when user move this page or view because you're using empty array for `useEffect`. This will run once page is loaded. This is not a good user experience. I have mentioned this in my question with an image